# Angular JS: Fire an event on editable-text change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a editable text, i want to fire an event when values changing not after changed. `e-ng-change` fire when value changed.

```
<span editable-text="user.displayName" onbeforesave="checkName($data)" e-ng-change="checkName"  e-form="userDisplayName"  edit-disabled="{{!user.displayName}}" e-maxlength="50" e-required ng-disabled="uiSelectForm.$waiting" onaftersave="updateUserProfile(true)">{{user.displayName}}</span>
              <a ng-click="userDisplayName.$show()" ng-hide="isVisitor || userDisplayName.$visible" >
                <span class="fa fa-pencil pencil-color"></span>
              </a>
```

Comment: can you please share your complete code?

Comment: Why don't use input field along with ng-model for two way data binding